# I keep getting an error in line 38 saying "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."

Tags: errors, arrays

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=8.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large\bf\LaTeX\ Example 6}
\end{center}
We can typeset array structures
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}=\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j}  & \mathbf{k} \\
     a_1  &      a_2        & a_3 \\
      b_1  &      b_2        & b_3
 \end{array}
 \right|
\end{equation}
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}=\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j}  & \mathbf{k} \\
 a_1  &  a_2   & a_3 \\
 b_1  &  b_2   & b_3
\end{array}
\right|
\end{equation}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Or
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots &  a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the last `array` you declared three columns but are using four; add another column

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=8.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large\bfseries\LaTeX\ Example 6
\end{center}
We can typeset array structures
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}=\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j}  & \mathbf{k} \\
     a_1  &      a_2        & a_3 \\
      b_1  &      b_2        & b_3
 \end{array}
 \right|
\end{equation}
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}=\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j}  & \mathbf{k} \\
 a_1  &  a_2   & a_3 \\
 b_1  &  b_2   & b_3
\end{array}
\right|
\end{equation}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Or
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots &  a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Not related to the question, but `\bf` is obsolete; use `\bfseries` instead; also, `center` forms a group so you don't need to explicitly group inside it:

```
\begin{center}
\large\bfseries\LaTeX\ Example 6
\end{center}
```

Comment: @BritneyWiggins: As Gonzalo's answer indicates, use `cccc` for your `array` column specification, or `*{4}{c}`.